# Avoid retrieving object to delete in many to many rel SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

Is there a way to avoid retrieving an object to delete in many-to-many relationship?

```
assign = Table('manytomany', Base.metadata,
    Column('pid', String(...), ForeignKey('parent.pid')),
    Column('cid', String(...), ForeignKey('child.cid'))
)

class Parent():
    ....
    childs = relationship("Child", secondary = assign, backref = 'parent')
```

I know I can do this:

```
obj = session.query(Table).get(pk_id)
session.delete(obj)
```

But I would like have only one database access, something like:

```
session.query(Table).filter_by(id = pk_id).delete()
```

I got an error because of the many-to-many rel:

> 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails...'

Is it possible?
Thx a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `session.query()` will always retrieve the object's data from the database first. To avoid that you will have to use the table object associated with your ORM object directly.

```
session.execute(Parent.__table__.delete().where(Parent.id==pk_id))
```

This will issue a single DELETE sql statement to the database removing the parent record. (`Parent.id` is a synonym for `Parent.__table__.c.id`)

To resolve the foreign key error you will have to delete the records in the assign table first.

```
session.execute(assign.delete().where(assign.c.pid==pk_id))
```

Comment: The foreign key error can probably also be solved by configuring cascading on the `childs` relationship. I have no experince with this myself but the documentation can be found [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#unitofwork-cascades).

Comment: Just to add to this answer a bit.  The where clause above can take `and_` from `sqlalchemy.sql.expression`.  So you can do `where(and_(Parent.id==pk_id, <<some other clause>>))` and chain that as much as you like.  Thanks though, this was a useful answer.